# In Ruby/Rails, how do I convert time duration (in string format) into milliseconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, time, formatting, milliseconds

I”m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have a time (duration) in the format

```
HH:MM:SS
```

For instance, “5:14:32” (5 hours, 14 minutes, and 32 seconds).  What can I do to take the string and convert it into milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
Time.parse("5:14:32").seconds_since_midnight * 1000 # 18872000.0
```

Comment: When the argument is "24:02" (24 minutes, 2 seconds), I'm getting the error, "argument out of range".

Comment: Well this works for me - Time.parse("0:24:02").seconds_since_midnight * 1000 # 1442000.0
You need to put 0 for hour.